# How to access data from findContours() in opencv js

Tags: opencv

Following this JS tutorial https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/daa/tutorial_js_contours_begin.html

```
// where data is a Uint8 image array
const cv_formatted_mat = new cv.matFromArray(height, width,
  cv.CV_8UC1, data);

cv.findContours(  cv_formatted_mat, contours, hierarchy, ...)

console.log(hierarchy.size())
// returns a number eg 12

console.log(hierarchy[0])  
// undefined
// expected some value since .size() returns a number
```

Example of hierarchy having values (MatVector), and showing a size (12), but selecting an element is undefined

[image]

```
console.log("hierarchy", hierarchy, hierarchy[0], hierarchy.size())
console.log("contours", contours, contours[0], contours.size())
```

[image]
How do we access the hierarchies?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `.get()` method.

```
let contour = contours.get(0)
console.log("contour", contour)
let Moments = cv.moments(contour, false)
console.log(Moments)
```

From https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dcf/tutorial_js_contour_features.html